# Why does C++23 string::resize_and_overwrite invoke operation as an rvalue?

Tags: c++, string, c++23

In order to improve the performance of writing data into `std::string`, C++23 specially introduced [`resize_and_overwrite()`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1072r10.html) for `std::string`. In [[string.capacity]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1072r10.html#string.capacity), the standard describes it as follows:

> ```
> template<class Operation>
> constexpr void resize_and_overwrite(size_type n, Operation op);
> ```
>
> 7. Let
>
>    — `o = size()` before the call to `resize_and_overwrite`.
>
>    — `k` be `min(o, n)`.
>
>    — `p` be a `charT*`, such that the range [`p`, `p + n`] is valid and `this->compare(0, k, p, k) == 0` is `true` before the call. The values in
>    the range [`p + k`, `p + n`] may be indeterminate [[basic.indet]](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.indet).
>
>    — `OP` be the expresion `std::move(op)(p, n)`.
>
>    — `r = OP`.
>
> [...]
>
> 10. Effects: Evaluates `OP`, replaces the contents of `*this` with [`p`, `p + r`), and invalidates all pointers and references to the range [`p`, `p + n`].

But I found out that this function will use `std::move` to convert `op` into an rvalue before invoking it, which means that we cannot pass in a callable that only has lvalue overloaded `operator()` ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xnjq61r16)):

```
#include <string>

int main() {
  struct Op {
    int operator()(char*, int) &;
    int operator()(char*, int) && = delete;
  } op;
  std::string s;
  s.resize_and_overwrite(42, op); // ill-formed
}
```

This behavior seems a bit strange, but since this change was made in
the [last edition](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1072r10.html#R10) of the paper, it is obviously intentional.

So, what are the considerations behind this? Is there any benefit in the mandate that `op` must be invoked as an rvalue?

Comment: It presumably is to permit calling with a move-only `op` (such as a one-time-consumable functor). It is relatively unusual to delete the rvalue-qualified operator. If you cannot take advantage of rvalue `*this`, you usually just fall back to unqualified.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`op` is only called once before it is destroyed, so calling it as an rvalue permits any `&&` overload on it to reuse any resources it might hold.

The callable object *is* morally an xvalue - it is "expiring" because it is destroyed immediately after the call. If you specifically designed your callable to only support calling as lvalues, then the library is happy to oblige by preventing this from working.